# awk insert in nth row if pattern not match in nth column of CSV

Tags: awk

I have CSV file as below , I need to compare 2nd column and insert the data in nth row .

CSV:

```
11-AUG-17,2,85,18120.4
11-AUG-17,4,112,2920
11-AUG-17,5,23,4181.92
11-AUG-17,6,284,74767.86
```

Input:

```
11-AUG-17,3,0,0
11-AUG-17,8,0,0
```

Desire Output:

```
11-AUG-17,2,85,18120.4
11-AUG-17,4,112,2920
11-AUG-17,5,23,4181.92
11-AUG-17,8,0,0
11-AUG-17,6,284,74767.86
11-AUG-17,3,0,0
```

I have tried the below `awk` command but it is inserting in all field as below

```
awk -F"," 'OFS="," $2!=3{print $1,3,0,0}1;$2!=8{print $1,12,0,0};' result1.csv >result2.csv
```

output of above command:

```
11-AUG-17,2,85,18120.4
11-AUG-17,3,0,0
11-AUG-17,8,0,0
11-AUG-17,4,112,2920
11-AUG-17,3,0,0
11-AUG-17,8,0,0
11-AUG-17,5,23,4181.92
11-AUG-17,3,0,0
11-AUG-17,8,0,0
11-AUG-17,6,284,74767.86
11-AUG-17,3,0,0
11-AUG-17,8,0,0
```

Thanks in advance for support

Comment: what is the logic of such order: `2, 4 , 5, 8, 6, 3` ? The question is unclear

Comment: no need to maintain order/sequence .just insertion is required in any row of CSV

Comment: You listed both an input CSV and an input. I assume you only meant to have one input. Which is the real input?

Answer (score 0):

Now, according to your words "***no need to maintain order/sequence .just insertion is required in any row of CSV***", simple `cat` command would be enough:

```
 cat input.csv >> first.csv
```

---

Final `first.csv` contents:

```
11-AUG-17,2,85,18120.4
11-AUG-17,4,112,2920
11-AUG-17,5,23,4181.92
11-AUG-17,6,284,74767.86
11-AUG-17,3,0,0
11-AUG-17,8,0,0
```

Comment: my requirement is to compare the 2nd column with static value   and if pattern not mach then only need to insert.